# Case insensitive ClearQuest queries

Tags: case-insensitive, clearquest

How can I make my clearquest search query case insensitive?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a write-up that may provide some insight...depending on what database you're using
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21130205